# Journalctl filling up with Gnome shell errors

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, systemd-journald

As of early this morning, the `journalctl` log is filling up with literally millions of errors, each of the form:

```
mei 07 08:04:47 Ophelia gnome-shell[2197]: JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties
                                           _onFocusChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:135:9
                                           popModal@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:587:22
                                           _continueDeactivate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:523:18
                                           deactivate/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:493:44
                                           finish@resource:///org/gnome/shell/gdm/authPrompt.js:517:13
                                           finish@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:845:26
                                           deactivate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:493:26
                                           _onUserBecameActive@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:305:18
                                           _wakeUpScreen@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:475:14
                                           _init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:554:69
                                           _countChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:272:18
                                           _sourceAdded/obj.sourceCountChangedId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/unlockDialog.js:201:18
                                           countUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/messageTray.js:791:15
                                           pushNotification@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/messageTray.js:852:14
                                           showNotification@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/messageTray.js:857:14
                                           processNotification@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/notificationDaemon.js:469:18
                                           _notifyForSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/notificationDaemon.js:355:16
                                           NotifyAsync@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/notificationDaemon.js:226:18
                                           _handleMethodCall@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:371:35
                                           _wrapJSObject/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:404:34
```

The exact text after the first few lines is sometimes different, but they all look like this. The computer was on at that time but I wasn't doing any work on it.
Besides, the gnome interface is noticeably slower today when I switch from one app window to another. If I run a `top` command in a terminal window and switch back and forth, I can clearly see the `systemd-journal` process eating 100% cpu for a while.

Does anyone notice something like this? Is this a bug in Gnome-shell?

**Edit**: the start of these errors coincides with an `unattended-upgrades` process. From the history, I can see that these packages were upgraded this morning:

```
firefox
firefox-locale-en
firefox-locale-nl
libapache2-mod-php7.4
libldap-2.4-2
libldap-common
php7.4-cli
php7.4-common
php7.4-json
php7.4-mysql
php7.4-readline
php7.4-opcache
```

None jumps out as the obvious culprit though.

Comment: Try deactivating all extensions and see if the error remains. If it doesn't, it means one of your extensions is corrupted

Comment: @Parto That is certainly the right direction - as soon as I deactivated the Dash-to-Panel extension, the desktop behaved very weirdly for a few seconds, then returned to normal, and the app switcher lag was gone. Better still, after I reactivated the extension, the delay and the CPU usage from `systemd-journal` did not come back. I did not check whether new error messages such as the above are still logged - it takes a lot of time to wade through millions of messages one screen at a time.

Comment: @Parto You can write up an answer if you like; otherwise, I'll do it myself.

Comment: No problem, you can just write one. Glad to have helped.

Comment: Today (on resume of session) Yep (experiencing that)..  Search engine pointed me here looking up the only clue on my somewhat unresponsive gnome-shell. I'm on *groovy* but almost the same I believe (my extensions are default, and no obvious crashes found either for me to file..)

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer to the question, but a workaround: deactivating and reactivating the Dash-to-Panel Gnome extension (on extensions.gnome.org) helped. That is, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switching from one application to another is now much faster, and `systemd-journal` does no longer take 100% after such a switch.

I haven't checked whether `journalctl` still displays that many errors, as they can only be viewed one screen at a time and there are still millions of messages. In a few days I'll clean up the log (with the `vacuum` keyword that I also discovered today) and report back here if the messages, contrary to expectations, still appear.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Dash-to-Panel extension is the one to blame since I'm suspicious about your statement "as soon as I deactivated the Dash-to-Panel extension, the desktop behaved very weirdly for a few seconds, then returned to normal,". That behavior is very similar to what you see when gnome-shell is restarted.

Comment: So, according to my theory, there was some other deficiency in the Dash-to-Panel extension which caused the gnome-shell to restart. There are a bunch of open bug reports telling the very same problem you're facing, and they usually solve the issue by killing the gnome-shell, and I believe that's what you've experienced; gnome-shell is restarted, fluctuated for a couple of seconds, then started to work without any issues.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1880405

Maybe an indicator reply stating that there're open bugs related to what you see could be beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

## Work around.

2 Edits to same file. Turn off logging to system-d journal.

```
FileName='/etc/systemd/journald.conf'
```

########## 1st edit ####################

## Line to replace

```
FindLine='#RateLimitIntervalSec='
```

## Show the line to edit

```
cat $FileName | grep --color -E "^|$FindLine"
```

## Replacement

```
ReplaceWith='#RateLimitIntervalSec=0s'
```

## Replace

```
sudo sed -i "/$REPLACE/c\$ReplaceWith" $FileName
```

## Show edited line

```
cat $FileName | grep --color -E "^|$FindLine"
```

[image]

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

###############  2nd edit ##########################

## Line to replace

```
FindLine='#RateLimitBurst='
```

## Show the line to edit

```
cat $FileName | grep --color -E "^|$FindLine"
```

## Replacement

```
ReplaceWith='#RateLimitBurst=0s'
```

## Replace

```
sudo sed -i "/$REPLACE/c\$ReplaceWith" $FileName
```

## Show edited line

```
cat $FileName | grep --color -E "^|$FindLine"
```

## Restart System-D Journal

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```